# Date Not Saving in Mysql from Php Registration Form

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble saving the date of birth in Mysql Db from Php registration form, what am I doing wrong?

1. Check.php

   `$month = $_POST['month'];
       $day = $_POST['day'];
       $year = $_POST['year'];

       mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB)VALUES ( $FirstName + "','" + $LastName + "','" + $Phone + "','" + $Year + "-" + $Month + "-" + $Day + ')") or  die("".mysql_error());
           echo "Successful Registration!";
   }`


   ?>
2. Registration Form

   Registration Form
           
               h3{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 22pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color:SlateBlue;
               text-align: center; text-decoration: underline }
               table{font-family: Calibri; color:white; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal;
               text-align:; background-color: SlateBlue; border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid navy}
               table.inner{border: 0px}

   ```
   <body>
       <form method="post" action="check.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <table width="300" border="0"<table align="center" cellpadding = "10">

           <tr>
               <td>FirstName:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="FirstName"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>LastName:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="LastName"></td>




           <tr>
           <td>Phone:</td>
           <td><input type="double" name="Phone"></td>



           <!----- Date Of Birth -------------------------------------------------------->
           <tr>
           <td>DATE OF BIRTH</td>

           <td>
           <select name="Birthday_day" id="Birthday_Day">
           <option value="-1">Day:</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>

           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
           <option value="6">6</option>
           <option value="7">7</option>
           <option value="8">8</option>
           <option value="9">9</option>
           <option value="10">10</option>
           <option value="11">11</option>
           <option value="12">12</option>

           <option value="13">13</option>
           <option value="14">14</option>
           <option value="15">15</option>
           <option value="16">16</option>
           <option value="17">17</option>
           <option value="18">18</option>
           <option value="19">19</option>
           <option value="20">20</option>
           <option value="21">21</option>

           <option value="22">22</option>
           <option value="23">23</option>
           <option value="24">24</option>
           <option value="25">25</option>
           <option value="26">26</option>
           <option value="27">27</option>
           <option value="28">28</option>
           <option value="29">29</option>
           <option value="30">30</option>

           <option value="31">31</option>
           </select>

           <select id="Birthday_Month" name="Birthday_Month">
           <option value="-1">Month:</option>
           <option value="January">Jan</option>
           <option value="February">Feb</option>
           <option value="March">Mar</option>
           <option value="April">Apr</option>
           <option value="May">May</option>
           <option value="June">Jun</option>
           <option value="July">Jul</option>
           <option value="August">Aug</option>
           <option value="September">Sep</option>
           <option value="October">Oct</option>
           <option value="November">Nov</option>
           <option value="December">Dec</option>
           </select>

           <select name="Birthday_Year" id="Birthday_Year">

           <option value="-1">Year:</option>
           <option value="1996">1996</option>
           <option value="1995">1995</option>
           <option value="1994">1994</option>
           <option value="1993">1993</option>
           <option value="1992">1992</option>
           <option value="1991">1991</option>
           <option value="1990">1990</option>

           <option value="1989">1989</option>
           <option value="1988">1988</option>
           <option value="1987">1987</option>
           <option value="1986">1986</option>
           <option value="1985">1985</option>
           <option value="1984">1984</option>
           <option value="1983">1983</option>
           <option value="1982">1982</option>
           <option value="1981">1981</option>
           <option value="1980">1980</option>

           <option value="1979">1979</option>
           <option value="1978">1978</option>
           <option value="1977">1977</option>
           <option value="1976">1976</option>
           <option value="1975">1975</option>
           <option value="1974">1974</option>
           <option value="1973">1973</option>
           <option value="1972">1972</option>
           <option value="1971">1971</option>
           <option value="1970">1970</option>

           <option value="1969">1969</option>
           <option value="1968">1968</option>
           <option value="1967">1967</option>
           <option value="1966">1966</option>
           <option value="1965">1965</option>
           <option value="1964">1964</option>
           <option value="1963">1963</option>
           <option value="1962">1962</option>
           <option value="1961">1961</option>
           <option value="1960">1960</option>

           <option value="1959">1959</option>
           <option value="1958">1958</option>
           <option value="1997">1957</option>
           <option value="1956">1956</option>
           <option value="1955">1955</option>
           <option value="1954">1954</option>
           <option value="1953">1953</option>
           <option value="1952">1952</option>
           <option value="1951">1951</option>
           <option value="1950">1950</option>

           <option value="1949">1949</option>
           <option value="1948">1948</option>
           <option value="1947">1947</option>
           <option value="1946">1946</option>
           <option value="1945">1945</option>
           <option value="1944">1944</option>
           <option value="1943">1943</option>
           <option value="1942">1942</option>
           <option value="1941">1941</option>
           <option value="1940">1940</option>

           <option value="1939">1939</option>
           <option value="1938">1938</option>
           <option value="1937">1937</option>
           <option value="1936">1936</option>
           <option value="1935">1935</option>
           <option value="1934">1934</option>
           <option value="1933">1933</option>
           <option value="1932">1932</option>
           <option value="1931">1931</option>
           <option value="1930">1930</option>

           <option value="1929">1929</option>
           <option value="1928">1928</option>
           <option value="1927">1927</option>
           <option value="1926">1926</option>
           <option value="1925">1925</option>
           <option value="1924">1924</option>
           <option value="1923">1923</option>
           <option value="1922">1922</option>
           <option value="1921">1921</option>
           <option value="1920">1920</option>

           <option value="1919">1919</option>
           <option value="1918">1918</option>
           <option value="1917">1917</option>
           <option value="1916">1916</option>
           <option value="1915">1915</option>
           <option value="1914">1914</option>
           <option value="1913">1913</option>
           <option value="1912">1912</option>
           <option value="1911">1911</option>
           <option value="1910">1910</option>


           </select>
           </td>
           </tr>



               </tr>
               <span style="size:10%;color:#FF0000"><?php if(isset($_GET["pass"])) { echo $_GET["pass"]; } ?></span>
               <tr>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="registration" /></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </form>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in concating in mysql query.

```
$FirstName + "','"
```

above is wrong.

use it as below.

```
'". $FirstName ."',
```

**Edit**

```
$date = $year."-".$Month."-".$Day;

INSERT INTO users 
    (FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB)
VALUES
( '". $FirstName ."','". $LastName ."','". $Phone ."','". $date ."')
```

Comment: Thanks for that but i think am even more confused now,

Comment: Do I do something like,  
       
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB)VALUES ( '". $FirstName ."''". $LastName ."', '". $Phone ."','". + $Year + "-" + $Month + "-" + $Day + ')") or  die("".mysql_error());
    echo "Successful Registration!";
}
?>

Comment: Tried the solution out but it didn't work out.. Thank You all the same

Comment: @KnightSlayer may i know the database structure...are you saving date in date fields..?

Comment: @KnightSlayer for birthdate you are accessing post variable as date year but actually your field name is as per `Birthday_Year` and so on so correct them first.

Comment: Dipesh, did corect that in my code, but the result am getting are still the same. It echoes "SUCCESSFUL REGISTRATION", but only registers 0000-00-00. Thank You!

Comment: @KnightSlayer meaning you are successfully adding record into database with `0000-00-00` as date...?

Comment: Yes that is what was happening but now it only saves as 1970-01-01

Comment: @KnightSlayer okay we are nearly there....now `echo $date;exit;` and see if date variable are all correct..

Comment: have tried that but it is only echoing the date of 1970-01-01, Thanks

Comment: @KnightSlayer is it live..?? what values you are posting..?

Comment: Yes it is live hosted live on Apache, am posting 5th Oct 1980, etc, etc but unfortunately the result is still the same, it is only saving as..."1970-01-01"

Answer (score 0):

Mysql query should be format like

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB)VALUES ( '".$FirstName."','". $LastName . "','" . $Phone . "','" . $Year . "-" . $Month + "-" . $Day . '")");
```

Comment: ... missing double quote after `$Day .`

Answer (score 0):

As others guys are saying, why not using PDO or MySQLi?

Your code will be more simple to code, and your code can be maintained over the time with other newer versions of PHP (**MySQL FUNCTION ARE DEPRECATED FROM PHP5.5**), e.g :

```
<?php

    $month = $_POST['month']; $day = $_POST['day']; $year = $_POST['year']; $dob = $_SESSION['dob'];
    $_SESSION['dob'] = $day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year;

    $stmt = $pdoconnect->prepare('INSERT INTO users(FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :phone, :dob)')
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'firstname' => $FirstName,
        'lastname' => $LastName,
        'phone' => $Phone,
        'dob'=> $dob
    ));

    echo "Successful Registration!"; 

?>
```

I include a solution for simplify DOB using session.

**EDIT (adding how to use pdo_mysql)** :

```
// $DNS contain host (mysql:host=localhost by default), the database name and MySQL port (port=3606 by default).
$dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=beathost_cms;port=3606';
// $user --> MySQL USER
$user = 'root';
// $pass --> MySQL PASSWORD
$pass = 'root*';
try {

            $pdoconnect = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
            $pdoconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die ('An error occured with MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution, but unfortuantely nothing is being saved into the Db, and neither is the "SUCCESSFUL REGISTRATION" being echoed.

Comment: @Knight Slayer, normal this is using PDO, you have to use PDO to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

You should

- fetch the correct POST-vars!!!!
- use the dot sign for string concaternation
- do a correct quotation
- take care of cases in varnames ($day is not $Day)
- dont put the unfiltered $_GET or $_POST vars into a query string
- dont use mysql_ functions, they are deprecated

this query should do what you want without errors:

```
$month = $_POST['Birthday_Month']; 
$day = $_POST['Birthday_day']; 
$year = $_POST['Birthday_Year']; 

$date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;

$query = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,Phone,DOB) VALUES ( '" . $FirstName . "','". $LastName . "','" . $Phone . "','" . $date . "')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT : I saw that you try to fetch the wrong POST-vars! You fetched $_POST['day'] but you need to fetch $_POST['Birthday_day'] which is the name of your select-field**

Comment: Thank You for that, it has echoed "SUCCESFUL REGISTRATION", but the date inserted into the db is in the form of 0000-00-00?

Comment: i had a wrong varname before, I corrected it. It was $Year instead of $year. Take care of cases in varnames.

Comment: And you should think about using PDO like in example of @RobotChief

Comment: have corrected that too but the result is still the same, the date is still being saved as 0000-00-00 in Mysql Db.

Comment: Have also tried that solution @Robotchief, but it didn't echo back "SUCCESSFUL REGISTRATION"..